# inner join in sql

Tags: sql, inner-join

```
SELECT TotalItems.Total_Items
  ,TotalItems.No_Items_Present
  ,ItemsTable.No_Of_Items_Ret 
FROM TotalItems 
INNER JOIN ItemsTable ON 
   ItemsTable.Item_Name= '" + DropItemName.SelectedValue + "'"
```

this is my SQL query what I want is to retrieve two column values corresponding to the item I enter in my dropdown list from one table and the `no_of_items_ret` from another table satisfying the condition of the dropdownlist

I'm getting all the values corresponding to any item I enter what should i do?

Comment: What the relationship between `ItemsTable` and `ItemsTable`? You need to put that in the `ON` clause. `ItemsTable.Item_Name= '" + DropItemName.SelectedValue + "'"` should be in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: it would be best if you posted (added in the question) the structure of these 2 tables (`TotalItems` and `ItemsTable`).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing the WHERE clause in SQL with the ON clause used to join tables.

Put your "filter condition" in a WHERE clause:

```
WHERE ItemsTable.Item_Name= '" + DropItemName.SelectedValue + "'"
```

The ON clause should contain the condition used to join the tables. For example:

```
TotalItems 
  INNER JOIN ItemsTable ON TotalItems.SOME_COLUMN = ItemsTable.SOME_OTHER_COLUMN
```

Answer (score 0):

Your join defines no relationship between TotalItems and ItemsTable, so all rows in the first table will be joined to all rows in the second.

If TotalItems and ItemsTable are related, you could do this:

```
Select 
  TotalItems.Total_Items,
  TotalItems.No_Items_Present,
  ItemsTable.No_Of_Items_Ret 
from TotalItems 
  INNER JOIN ItemsTable 
    ON ItemsTable.ItemID = TotalItems.ItemID
WHERE ItemsTable.Item_Name= '" + DropItemName.SelectedValue + "'"
```

Comment: just a quibble: its not "all rows in both tables" but rather all the row in the totalitems table will be cross joined with all the tables in the itemstable table where the name = the selected value

Answer (score 0):

ItemsTable.Item_Name= '" + DropItemName.SelectedValue + "'"

looks like it should be after the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT TotalItems.Total_Items
,TotalItems.No_Items_Present
,ItemsTable.No_Of_Items_Ret 
FROM TotalItems 
INNER JOIN ItemsTable ON TotalItems.[reference] = ItemsTable.[reference]
WHERE ItemsTable.Item_Name= '" + DropItemName.SelectedValue + "'"
```

reference should be the field that ties the tables together.